# Magento Enterprise Edition to Community Edition

Tags: magento

If I Purchase enterprise edition, do I need to pay the amount every year if I don’t want any support from the magento team ?

Comment: Typically when you're spending $10,000+ on something, the person you're paying that $10,000+ to is the one you want to ask abut licensing terms.

Comment: Actually I need to change the enterprise edition to community. So can I use the existing codes and database ?

Comment: An experienced Magento might be able to pull that off.  You could not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Afaik yes, even if you *don't want* to have support or *don't use* the support, you nevertheless have to pay the full license costs ($14,420 for a single EE production server per year, as of this writing).

You can contact their sales team and try to make your own deal, of course. Looking at the EE price hiking over the past years (EE started at $8,900 per year, now it's $14,420) I don't believe there's leeway, but you'll never know before you ask^^